# Except for python, is there any other language supporting negative index?

Tags: indexing, negative-integer

I just wonder is there any other programming language to support negative index.

About C, the pointer can be calculated just like number. so please except it.

But in python,  my_list[-1]  is the last of list.

Is Python the only language supporting such a negative indexing concept?

your answer will be helpful, with various language experience. :)

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Pascal does, but negative index in Pascal does not represent reversed index as Python.

Comment: Thank you for you kind answer:)  it is helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)) article,

- `Ch`
- `LiveCode`
- `Mathematica`
- `Python`
- `Ruby`
- `S-Lang`
- `Wolfram Language`

Can use Negative indexing for accessing the array elements from the last.